# How to secure Angular 6 - Spring boot micro service application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to discuss about my attempt to re write an existing app and would like to know the suggestions to make the app more secure.

We have a banking application its not a client facing application its for the bank employees to manage the Internet banking users and systems . its called admin portal .
currently it is written in java , jetspeed framework . i would like to re write it with Angular 6 and spring boot micro service architecture.

Am familiar with the spring boot and the spring rest , but am not sure about the security part . since its a banking app we have to take the security part more serious. 
We are using MySQl as Database  .

Could anyone please share what would be the best security approach among JWT and OAuth 2 in this case? How it can be implemented with spring security ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed two home banking application and come up with two choices for authentication/authorization part: `JWT` and `OAuth2` and i choose the first

`JWT` is simpler to manage and also secure and doens't need an `Authorization Server` that can compromise scalability of your application (you have to scale also this service)

For `JWT` the approaches are two, i've chosen the second:

1. you can write a authentication microservice to generate and decode the token (and you could have scalability problem as an OAuth Service)
2. you can write a logic to generate `JWT` token in your `Gateway(s)` application and all the others `Microservices` must have the security part to decode the token.

With the second approach every microservices knows if that token has roles (because roles are encoded in the token itself) and the authorization is very fine grained. The alternative it's to place authorization on `Gateway` layer, but i think it will become very complicated.

On angular-side you have only to implement a login with a token as response. Set the token in every request in your `Authorization` header.
And site navigation you could implmenet a call that for a defined token, the server will retrieve user `ROLES` and route to a specific page only if the user (token) has that `ROLES`

Also if i hack JS in some way (that could be quite difficult with minify/obfuscation) i will be able to route frontend application in a page not authorized but the server side call will fail and the `lamer` will se an empty page.

Moreover in home banking application you can use operation across devices or use OTP authentication for operative provisions